# How can I ssh to a remote ubuntu laptop using username/hostname and password?

Tags: ssh

I am using the `ssh username@hostname` command to ssh into a remote ubuntu host from my local ubuntu laptop. That does not seem to work. Also it shows me the wrong IP address when I run in verbose on it

```
local@penguin:~$ ssh -v remote@penguin
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to penguin [192.168.0.1] port 22.
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 1):

You would want to connect to the external IP, so the ssh command would be something like the lines of:

```
$ ssh remote@www.penguin.com
```

Or

```
$ ssh remote@54.23.45.22
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work. penguin is the hostname of the remote machine. And I do not know the IP address.

Comment: @PeterJ can you do `ping peguin` and see what it returns?